# Pig Latin Translator in C++

Tags: c++, pig-latin

I made this Pig Latin translator in C++ and I was wondering what I could improve and what is good about it.

I used the stringstream class to get the individual words.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
std::string translate(std::string word){
   if(word.length() > 1){
       word += word[0];
       word[0] -= word[0];
       word += "ay";
   }
   return word;
}
int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::string str = "Hello the world has ended";
    std::stringstream stringStream(str);
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        std::string currentWord;
        stringStream >> currentWord;
        v.push_back(currentWord);
    }

for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
    std::cout << translate(v[i]) + " ";
}

std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Your implementation is incorrect.  It doesn't trap words starting with vowels or words starting with compound consonants(eg. "th") as special cases.

Comment: `word[0] -= word[0];`: AHHHHHHHHHHHH!!!

Comment: The only thing I have to add to Loki's answer is that you should separate IO and logic. Keep your IO in `main()` and the processing of the string should be in another function. That other function should return a `string` which then can call `cout` in `main`. This way the code is usable in other contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of issues:

This appends the first letter of the word onto the end.

```
       word += word[0];
```

Since I don't know what "PigLatin" is I can't tell if this is correct. A comment about what is the expected translation is really required so we can understand if this is correct behavior.

This sets the first letter to `0`.

```
       word[0] -= word[0];
```

Note: **NOT** the character `0` but the number zero which is an unprintable character (there are no glyphs that represent the number `0`). Note the character `0` is represented by the number 48 (in ASCII or UTF-8).

Did you want to remove the first character from the string?

```
word = word.substr(1); // Gets the substring from 1 to the end.
                       // Assigns it to the variable word.
```

Adds the string "ay" to the end of word.

```
       word += "ay";
```

Sure. Sounds reasonable. But need to understand the expected behavior/

You have a string. Which you are converting into a sequence of words and storing in `v`.

```
    std::vector<std::string> v;
```

But the only thing you do with `v` is loop over it and get each word to call `translate()` with. Why not remove the middle man and not use the container at all.

Here You are creaging a loop as long as the string. But each iteration you are taking a word from the string.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
```

So this will have a lot of blank words on the end. A better way is to read words from the stream until there are no more words in the stream.

```
    while (stringStream >> currentWord) {
        // Do stuff with currentWord
    }
```

Avoid the use of `std::endl`.

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Its probably not doing any harm here. But its a bad habit. The difference between `\n` and `std::endl` is that `std::endl` also flushes the buffer. Manually forcing a buffer flush is usually incorrect. The buffers will auto flush at the optimal time. Program inserted flushing is usually wrong and is a major cause of eniffciency in C++ code.

I would refactor the inner loop like this:

```
    while (stringStream >> currentWord) {
        std::cout << translate(std::move(currentWord)) + " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
```

Notice the `std::move()` this moves an object to the function (saves a copy). So at the `translate()` needs to be changed slightly.

```
std::string translate(std::string&& word)
{                                ^^  bind a moved parameter.
   // stuff.
   return word;
}
```

Comment: When you say "bind a moved parameter" what do you mean. I am reasonably new to C++.

Comment: When you use `std::move()` to pass a parameter to a function it will find functions that will accept the parameter with `&&` on it.